# React Router Link changes URL but not view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an App.js, that looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PdfViewer from './components/PdfViewer';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './history';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage'
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
      <Route path="/pdfviewer" component={PdfViewer} />
      </Switch>      
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

inside a nested component i have a `<Link>` like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import DashboardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Dashboard';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const MainListItems = () => {
  return(
  <Link to="/">
  <div>
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <DashboardIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
    </ListItem>

  </div>
  </Link>
  )}
```

here is my component, that renders a Link. 
When it is clicked, the Url changes, but it does not render a new component... how come?

Comment: `Link` needs to be a child of a `Router` component.  Is `MainListItems` located inside of a router?

Comment: @Kyle yes it is part of both componets. It is inside a `<Navbar>` component, that wraps every component

Comment: I'm not seeing what the problem could be.  Can you please place this in a code sandbox for me to look at?  Something simple.  Start with this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-boilerplate-8ucq4